# Make: Compile .c files of rule

Tags: makefile

Say I have the following rule in my Makefile:

```
foo: foo1.c foo2.c head1.h head2.h
    gcc -o $@ foo1.c foo2.c
```

As you can see, in this case - as in most cases- the .c files in the rule correspond to the .c files you pass to gcc. My question is, is there a variable that can be passed to a Makefile which would evaluate to "all the .c files in the rule"?

Personally, I use the following:

```
CFILES=$(filter %.c,$^)                                                        

foo: foo1.c foo2.c head1.h head2.h
    gcc -o $@ $(CFILES)
```

but I'm not sure if this is the correct way...

Answer (score 0):

I guess your filter is fine, but I'd rather define separately the lists of `.c` and `.h` files and use those lists where appropriate:

```
CFILES=foo1.c foo2.c
HFILES=head1.h head2.h

foo: $(CFILES) $(HFILES)
        gcc -o $@ $(CFILES)
```

If you don't mix `.c` and `.h` in the first place, there's no need to separate them afterwards.

Comment: That's an option but consider a Makefile where there are many of these lines. You 'd resort to use CFILES1,2,3 etc and it would make much more mess. I'm looking if `make` has a native way to do this. It seems to me as a pretty reasonable feature for `make` to have.

Comment: make would need to have a paired set of this sort of filter for each implicit rule to even begin for this to work (and since it wouldn't be able to apply those automatically in this case anyway I'm not sure that would even make sense to bother with).